# How to write In query on entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a SQL query which selects top 5000 data with some where conditions. Now my question is how can i write this same query from entity-framework? Is it possible? I wanted know the most effeciant way to achive this query from entity-framework.

Query:

```
select TOP 5000 * from MyData where Type=1 and UPC not in (
select UPC from MyData where Type=2 AND UPC IS NOT NULL)
```

C# Entity:

```
using (var ctx = new db_ProductionEntities())
{
    //var items = ctx.MyData.Take(10).ToList(); need to know how to write query here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var answer = (from d1 in ctx.MyData 
              where d1.Type == 1 and 
                    !(from d2 in ctx.MyData 
                      where d2.Type == 2 and d2.UPC != null
                      select d2.UPC 
                     ).Contains(d1.UPC)
              order by d1.Id //or some other field, it's needed for "Take"
              select d1).Take(5000).ToList();
```